# Is there a way to combine two videos interlaced frame by frame with a single ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have two videos and I want to go through them frame by frame
taking one frame from video 1, followed by 1 frame of video 2
then the next frame of video 1, followed by the next frame of video 2.

Like depicted in the following image:

[image: Example of input and output]

Or, if the image does not load:

```
Video 1: [a][b][c]
Video 2: [1][2][3]
Result:  [a][1][b][2][c][3]
```

The way I have done it now is by using `ffmpeg` to convert every
video to a series of `png` files on disk. Renaming them and then
combining them back into a single video:

`ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %03d.png -c:v libx265 -preset slow -crf 23 output4.mp4`

```
Note: The input videos were each 30fps, so I selected 60fps for the output.
```

Is there a way to do this using `ffmpeg` in a single command without storing all frames on disk first?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [interleave](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#interleave_002c-ainterleave) filter.

```
ffmpeg -i video1 -i video2 -filter_complex "[0]settb=AVTB,setpts=N/30/TB[v0];[1]settb=AVTB,setpts=N/30/TB[v1];[v0][v1]interleave=n=2" out.mp4
```